# UITextView disappearing text on new line

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Im trying to do custom message text field in SwiftUI. When I start typing into the text field, everything is ok. I can hit enter and jump to newline without any issues, but when I reach the end of the line, the text disappears.

Here is the code:

```
struct MessageInputField: UIViewRepresentable {
var inputMessage: Binding<String>
var currentFieldHeight: Binding<CGFloat>

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
    let textView = UITextView(frame: .zero) 
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    textView.delegate = context.coordinator
    textView.textContainerInset = .zero
    textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
    textView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
    textView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
    return textView
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
    uiView.text = inputMessage.wrappedValue
    updateTextViewHeight(uiView)
}

private func updateTextViewHeight(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let size = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: textView.frame.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude))

        // Calculate max height for 5 lines
        let maxHeight = textView.font!.lineHeight * 5

        // Limit textView height and enable scrolling when content exceeds max height
        if size.height >= maxHeight {
            currentFieldHeight.wrappedValue = maxHeight
            textView.isScrollEnabled = true
            if textView.frame.size.height != maxHeight {
                textView.frame.size.height = maxHeight
            }
        } else {
            currentFieldHeight.wrappedValue = size.height
            textView.isScrollEnabled = false
            if textView.frame.size.height != size.height {
                textView.frame.size.height = size.height
            }
        }
}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
    var parent: MessageInputField

    init(_ parent: MessageInputField) {
        self.parent = parent
    }

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        parent.inputMessage.wrappedValue = textView.text
        parent.updateTextViewHeight(textView)
    }
}
```

}

Here is the issue:

[image: xxx]

Comment: check these links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60437014/frame-height-problem-with-custom-uiviewrepresentable-uitextview-in-swiftui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58670201/uitextview-adjust-size-based-on-the-content-in-swiftui, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56471973/how-do-i-create-a-multiline-textfield-in-swiftui/58639072#58639072

Comment: I can confirm the issue. If text reaches the end of the line, the view's height is growing, but not the view's textContainer height, until text size is large enough o fill 5 lines and becomes visible.

Answer (score 0):

A small change will fix the issue:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MessageInputField: UIViewRepresentable {
    var inputMessage: Binding<String>
    var maximumLines: Int
    var currentFieldHeight: Binding<CGFloat>
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView(frame: .zero)
        textView.isScrollEnabled = true // <- HERE!
        textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        textView.textContainerInset = .zero
        textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
        textView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        textView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
        return textView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = inputMessage.wrappedValue
        updateTextViewHeight(uiView)
    }
    
    private func updateTextViewHeight(_ textView: UITextView) {
        let size = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: textView.frame.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        
        // Calculate max height
        let maxHeight = textView.font!.lineHeight * CGFloat(maximumLines)
        
        // Limit textView height and enable scrolling when content exceeds max height
        if size.height >= maxHeight {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                currentFieldHeight.wrappedValue = maxHeight // main queue avoids runtime warning: "Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior."
            }
            if textView.frame.size.height != maxHeight {
                textView.frame.size.height = maxHeight
            }
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                currentFieldHeight.wrappedValue = size.height // main queue avoids runtime warning: "Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior."
            }
            if textView.frame.size.height != size.height {
                textView.frame.size.height = size.height
            }
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        var parent: MessageInputField
        
        init(_ parent: MessageInputField) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            parent.inputMessage.wrappedValue = textView.text
            parent.updateTextViewHeight(textView)
        }
    }
}
```

**The key is that `textView.isScrollEnabled` is now always true**, so the textContainer can adjust its height. There's no problem with the scroll indicator because it's anyways only visible when the text is larger than the available space.

As a side note, the binding's value should be changed on the main queue to avoid complaints.

Note also that `MessageInputField` needs to be wrapped in a frame modifier to respect `maxHeight`.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var string = ""
    @State private var height: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MessageInputField(inputMessage: $string, maximumLines: 5, currentFieldHeight: $height)
                .frame(height: height)
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

I added a `maximumLines` parameter to make this view reusable.